# jQuery autocomplete does everything but fill its own field

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have a simple text input with autocomplete on it:

```
<input type="text" class="span4" id="autoc1" name="agent" value="">
```

I am using the following jquery code to action the autocomplete and bring back the data. Then on one click I want to fill two inputs with data returned. Everything works as it should apart from the actual field with autocomplete on it doesn't get filled.

Jquery:

```
$(function() {
    // input id of field with autoc on        
    $( "#autoc1" ).autocomplete({

        // php mysql data get
        source: "/pages/includes/getAgent.php",            
        minLength: 2,

        select: function( event, ui ) {
            //alert(ui.item.agent_name); //  shows correct info, here only to test

            //tried $(this) as below - didn't work
            //$(this).val(ui.item.agent_name);

              $('#autoc1').val(ui.item.agent_name); //  tried with and without this, didn't work
              $('#comm').val(ui.item.commission_percent); // this works perfectly!!
        }
    }).data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li>" )
        .append( "<a>" + item.agent_name + "</a>" )
        .click(function(){$('#autoc1').val(item.agent_name)}) // added this. didn't work
        .appendTo( ul );
    };
});
```

This is the JSON returned if helpful:

```
[{"0":"agent a","agent_name":"agent a","1":"15","commission_percent":"15"},
{"0":"agent b","agent_name":"agent b","1":"10","commission_percent":"10"}]
```

Run out of ideas completely!

**EDIT**

More html, its a basic form, simple

```
<form class="add_booking" method="post">

    <input type="text" placeholder="Date" class="span2" id="datepicker" name="date" value="<?=$showDate?>">

    <input type="text" placeholder="Booking Agent" class="span4 here" id="autoc1" name="agent" value="<?=$ds['agent']?>">

    <input type="text" placeholder="15" class="span1" name="commission" id="comm" value="<?=$ds['show_comm_percent']?>">%

etc etc </form>
```

Comment: try `$(this).find('input').val(ui.item.agent_name);`

Comment: @MostafaShahverdy Thanks but didn't work.

Comment: Will you please give us more from your HTML file? where is `#comm` ?

Comment: I think `$( "#autoc1" ).autocomplete({})` is changing layout and creating a new `input`. Using chrome, right click on your input, inspect element and check if input with id `#autoc1` is out there.

Comment: This is from chrome: <input type="text" placeholder="Booking Agent" class="span4 ui-autocomplete-input" id="autoc1" name="agent" value="" autocomplete="off"> you would think that fact that it adds ui-autocomplete-input to class would mean it would add the autocomplete? Makes sense to me but not happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the part of your code where you're doing:

```
data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem
```

You're messing around with the internal data and functions of jQuery's autocomplete. You shouldn't do that.

I think the reason why it is not working is that you're passing invalid things into autocomplete:

> There are two supported formats: An array of strings: [ "Choice1",
>   "Choice2" ] An array of objects with label and value properties: [ {
>   label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]

But you are passing in custom data. To do that (without meddling with Autocomplete's own functions) you should use a function data source:

```
Function: The third variation, a callback, provides the most flexibility and can be used to connect any data source to Autocomplete. The callback gets two arguments:
A request object, with a single term property, which refers to the value currently in the text input. For example, if the user enters "new yo" in a city field, the Autocomplete term will equal "new yo".
A response callback, which expects a single argument: the data to suggest to the user. This data should be filtered based on the provided term, and can be in any of the formats described above for simple local data. It's important when providing a custom source callback to handle errors during the request. You must always call the response callback even if you encounter an error. This ensures that the widget always has the correct state.
```

The example given is:

```
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
          var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
          response( $.grep( tags, function( item ){
              return matcher.test( item );
          }) );
      }
});
```

As you are getting data from a server, you would need to store the response function while you make an ajax call to the server, and the call it when the data is returned.

If however you want to keep using your version when you use a custom data format and over-ride the internal functions, to make it work you can add `return false` to the select function.

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
    $('#autoc1').val(ui.item.agent_name); //  tried with and without this, didn't work
    $('#comm').val(ui.item.commission_percent); // this works perfectly!!
    return false;
}
```

The reason this works is that you're now setting the value of the field manually, and returning false stops autocomplete from trying to set the value of the field itself (and failing as it doesn't know what to set the field to).

The reason I know that is that I wanted autocomplete in my app to automatically submit the selected value as if the user had pressed enter after selecting the value. The way to do that was to do:

```
autocompleteSelect: function(event, suggestItems){
    var suggestItem = suggestItems.item;
    $(this.element).find('.tagInput').val(suggestItem.value);
    $(this.element).find('.tagInput').blur(); //This triggers the onchange function elsewhere
    $(this.element).find('.tagInput').val("");
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how then do you explain the alert working correctly and the passing of the 2nd variable to its correct input?

Comment: I don't know. If you want to investigate it, you could try returning false from your 'select' function, after doing '$('#autoc1').val(ui.item.agent_name);'. I think autocomplete sets the value after calling the select function, and may be getting confused as it doesn't know what to set it to.

Comment: wtf!!! i added 'return false;' after $('#autoc1').val(ui.item.agent_name); $('#comm').val(ui.item.commission_percent); and it works! Absolutely makes no sense whatsoever but thanks for the idea